# SMTP - GSSAPI operation failed with error - Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information (Cannot find KDC for realm)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, smtp

When I try to send mail with smtp client, I get this error from my mail server. I could not find the problem. Does anyone have an idea?

My SMTP code:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("10.0.188.30", 587);
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mailtest@company.local", "Paris2024!");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("mailtest@company.local"), new MailAddress(user.Email));
client.EnableSsl = false;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Subject = subject;
message.Body = body;
await client.SendMailAsync(message);
```

Error :

GSSAPI operation failed with error - Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information (Cannot find KDC for realm "company.local").